# Change path to store image while using wysihtml5 and dragonfly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, image-upload, wysihtml5, dragonfly-gem

I am using `wysihtml5` gem (https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-wysihtml5). It also uses `activeadmin-dragonfly` gem. Currently, it stores images under public folder. I am using rails 4. I need to know a way to change this path.

Comment: Any progress with this issue? I'm running into the same problem. It seems like [activeadmin-dragonfly](https://github.com/stefanoverna/activeadmin-dragonfly) needs to be configured but I'm not sure how to configure it.

Comment: @DogEatDog now I am configuring my app to save images to cloudinary(as the images get cleaned up on heroku). You can refer this doc http://markevans.github.io/dragonfly/v0.9.15/file.Configuration.html. Hope it helps:)